in-built microphone not detected
My laptop was running on windows 11 before ubuntu. When I installed the windows 11, the same thing happened and I had to install additional drivers with usb drive. I am new to ubuntu so I tried to follow all the instructions that I could find but somehow none of them working
Some of the things I did:

Checking sound settings it says no input devices
using alsamixer
reinstalling alsa-base pulseaudio
changing download server
installing amd drivers
changing nvidia drivers


Follow what instructions? Please edit the question and add this info.
